# IAsyncResult out string always null

Tags: c#, asynchronous, callback, null

My string message ist always null, also my Result AsyncState ist null.
Someone see the mistake?

```
private void create_Incident(string computer_idn, string swidn_choice,
                             string swName_choice, string CI_Number,
                             string windows_user)
{
    string msg_id = "" + computer_idn + "_" + swidn_choice + "";
    string username = "BISS";

    server3.ILTISAPI api = new server3.ILTISAPI();
    api.BeginInsertIncident(username, "", msg_id, "", "", "2857",
        "BISS - Software Deployment", "", "", "NOT DETERMINED", "", "", "", "",
        "", "", "5 - BAU", "3 - BAU", "", "Interface", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
        delegate(IAsyncResult r) { InsertIncidentCallback(api, r); }, null);
}

private void InsertIncidentCallback(server3.ILTISAPI api,
                                    IAsyncResult result)
{
    // do something and then:
    string message;
    api.EndInsertIncident(result, out message);
}
```

Return values: <0 Error (further information can be found in the msg parameter). =0 OK. =1 OK.
The Methods with details:

```
public IAsyncResult BeginInsertIncident(string userName, string password, 
                                        string MsgId, string ThirdPartyRef, 
                                        string Type, string EmployeeId, 
                                        string ShortDescription, string Details,
                                        string Category, string Service, 
                                        string  OwnerGrp, string OwnerRep, 
                                        string SecondLevelGrp, 
                                        string SecondLevelRep, 
                                        string ThirdLevelGrp, 
                                        string ThirdLevelRep, string Impact, 
                                        string Urgency, string Priority, 
                                        string Source, string Status, 
                                        string State, string Solution, 
                                        string ResolvedDate, string Cause, 
                                        string Approved, AsyncCallback callback, 
                                        object asyncState);

public int EndInsertIncident(IAsyncResult asyncResult, out string msg);
```

I want to check the msg, if there is a error or ok.

Comment: Well the AsyncState *would* be null - you're passing in `null` as the final argument to `BeginInsertIncident`.

Comment: Given that the only incidence of the terms BeginInsertIncident & EndInsertIncident found in our favourite search engine is this question, how are we meant to guess what's happening? -1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The async-state is the spare `object` that you pass in. You are passing in `null` (as the final parameter); therefore the `AsyncState` is always going to be `null`.

If you don't want `null`, pass something else in as the final parameter.

Comment: is the AsyncState necessary for the message? I want to make a if query to find out the messagenumber. 
"Return values: <0 Error (further information can be found in the msg parameter). =0 OK. =1 OK."

Comment: @ManuelFischer then you need to catch the return value from `EndInsertIncident`; this has nothing whatsoever to do with async-state, though. The purpose of async-state is to carry some information *entirely specific to the caller* to the callback - so that your callback can know the context to which it is being invoked.

Comment: okay, but its little misterious, why I dont get any information through the out string msg, isnt it?

Comment: when I delete the employee_ID, the message give a error. But when I use a correct employee ID, nothing is in the message...

Comment: oh man...I talked the API developer and he found my incidents. So null means 0, the documentation is wrong...